# Parsing variable number of values into mysql table using python

Tags: python, mysql, parsing

I have a large text file of a drug database. Each drug begins with:

```
#BEGIN DRUGCARD _______
```

Within each Drug there are several categories. The categories of interest for me are:

```
# Drug_Target_1_ID
(some number i.e. 3421)

# Drug_Target_1_Name         NOTE: this is the corresponding name for the ID above
(some target i.e. hormone receptor)
```

At this point I successively generated code to parse the file and find these values of interest and put them into a table. The next steps get a little tricky though:

There are variable amounts of Targets for each drug:
i.e. some drugs have:

```
`# Drug_Target_1_ID`

`# Drug_Target_1_Name`


`# Drug_Target_12_ID`

`# Drug_Target_12_Name`

...

`# Drug_Target_4_ID`

`# Drug_Target_4_Name`

(NOTE these are also not necessarily in numerical order!)
```

The biggest number I've seen in the file is ~100, but the majority of drugs have between 1-10 on average.

There are duplicates! Each drug ID is unique and corresponds to the drug Name but certain ones repeat. 
i.e. Many drugs might have the same target and therefore the ID/Name show up again.

What I'd like to do is create a MASTER list/table of all UNIQUE IDs/Names. So basically scan through all fields that have `Drug_Target_#_ID/ Drug_Target_#_Name` and add each unique one into a table that can be manipulated later. Within the original file the target IDs are NOT in any order.

Would I have to create code that searches each drugcard (`#BEGIN DRUGCARD ____`) and each `Drug_Target_#` individually

My **inefficient** code:

```
TO_GET = ["# Drug_Target_1_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_2_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_3_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_4_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_5_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_6_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_7_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_8_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_9_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_10_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_11_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_12_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_13_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_14_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_15_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_16_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_17_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_18_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_19_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_20_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_21_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_22_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_23_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_24_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_25_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_26_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_27_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_28_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_29_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_30_ID", \
      "# Drug_Target_1_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_2_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_3_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_4_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_5_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_6_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_7_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_8_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_9_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_10_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_11_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_12_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_13_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_14_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_15_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_16_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_17_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_18_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_19_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_20_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_21_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_22_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_23_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_24_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_25_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_26_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_27_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_28_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_29_Name", \
      "# Drug_Target_30_Name", \
```

Then later:

```
      try:
    target_name = drugbank_all[drug]["# Drug_Target_1_Name"]
    target_id= "INSERT INTO TargetID_TargetName (Drug_Target_1_ID, Drug_Target_1_Name) VALUES(\"%s\", \"%s\");" % (accession[0], target_name[0])
    cur.execute (target_id)
    print "target_id done"
except KeyError:
    print "Drug target 1 not found, skipping..."
    pass
```

...For EACH one?

Problems with this approach:

- Sloppy
- Doesn't ignore duplicates
- Doesn't figure out how many Drug_Target's there are it just tries as many as I specify (which is not very concise)

Questions:

1. Is there a way to do a for loop that searches for how many Drug_targets for each DRUGCARD there are before parsing then parsing accordingly?
2. Is there a way to quickly scan the list to see if a number as already been attributed and then ignore the entry?

UPDATE: actual data

```
#BEGIN_DRUGCARD DB00097

# AHFS_Codes:
Not Available

# ATC_Codes:
G03GA08

# Absorption:
The mean absolute bioavailability following a single subcutaneous injection to healthy     female volunteers is about 40%.     

...

# Drug_Target_1_HPRD_ID:
01073

# Drug_Target_1_ID:
148

# Drug_Target_1_Locus:
2p21

# Drug_Target_1_Molecular_Weight:
78617

# Drug_Target_1_Name:
Lutropin-choriogonadotropic hormone receptor

...

# Drug_Target_2_HGNC_ID:
HGNC:3969

# Drug_Target_2_HPRD_ID:
00639

# Drug_Target_2_ID:
430

# Drug_Target_2_Locus:
2p21-p16

# Drug_Target_2_Molecular_Weight:
78296

# Drug_Target_2_Name:
Follicle-stimulating hormone receptor
```

Comment: Can you provide an actual example of the file format?

Comment: Seems like the ideal problem domain for a parser like [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) or [SimpleParse](http://simpleparse.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @paulo I will definitely check those out now- thanks!

Comment: @LyndsySimon- 
Edit: Crap I can't format this correctly. how do I format it like in the original post? Sorry!

the format is quite long and there is a bunch of other stuff between the actual parts I need. I will be happy to post some of it though:


    #BEGIN_DRUGCARD DB00097

    # AHFS_Codes:
    Not Available

    # ATC_Codes:
    G03GA08

    ...

    # Drug_Target_1_ID:
    148

    ....

Comment: @Jean-Francois Corbett-thanks for making my post nicer!

Comment: @LyndsySimon- I'm an idiot- added actual code to the original post